# Android: highlight the user-input words in the result

Tags: android

My app implements Sqlite FTS(and Android Search Tool). I would like the result in the `TextView` have the input words/strings highlighted.

If user Input string "Cats rule" I would like to make those two words appear with different font color in all the returned result set.

Can anyone please guide me.

I am using `ListView` with `CursorAdapter`, if this info is needed.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The code is highlighting a word. But it highlights only last occurrence of a word if there are multiple occurrences

```
final SpannableStringBuilder spannableEng = new SpannableStringBuilder(english);
        final ForegroundColorSpan spanEng = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);

        for (String word : qStr) {
            final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(english);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                spannableEng.setSpan(
                        spanEng, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                );
            }
        }
        viewHolder.engTextV.setText(spannableEng);
```

**UPDATE 2**
I solved it. Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer to similar question

```
  final SpannableStringBuilder spannableEng = new SpannableStringBuilder(english);

        for (String word : qStr) {
            final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+word+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(english);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                final ForegroundColorSpan spanEng = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
                spannableEng.setSpan(
                        spanEng, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                );
            }
        }
        viewHolder.engTextV.setText(spannableEng);
```

Make sure `final ForegroundColorSpan spanEng = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);` is inside your loop.